# uWSGI "Killed" shortly after starting

Tags: python, docker, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I'm trying to run my Flask api on a uWSGI development server. In my uwsgi.ini, I have:

```
[uwsgi]
module = api
callable = app
master = true
```

When I run `uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:5002 --protocol uwsgi --ini ./uwsgi.ini`, it starts running correctly, printing that it is loading one of my models, but then it just says "Killed" and exits. How can I get more information about why it's exiting? Thanks.

The full output:

```
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from ./uwsgi.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.18 (64bit) on [Mon Jul 15 19:55:29 2019] ***
compiled with version: 6.3.0 20170516 on 15 July 2019 18:05:17
os: Linux-4.9.125-linuxkit #1 SMP Fri Sep 7 08:20:28 UTC 2018
nodename: b8e2862b0584
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 2
current working directory: /opt/app/Paraphrasing/Paraphrase_Demo
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) ***
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1048576
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 0.0.0.0:5002 fd 3
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) ***
Python version: 3.7.3 (default, Jun 11 2019, 01:05:09)  [GCC 6.3.0 20170516]
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x5646a0f5a310
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) ***
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 145840 bytes (142 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
WRN: Linux system doesn't support windows job object yet. OS: Unix 4.9.125.0
Set device to: -2
Load model from /opt/app/en_v0.4/model.11
Model loaded in 3691ms
Loading Finish from Files: 07/15/2019 19:55:36
The pre-trained model you are loading is a cased model but you have not set `do_lower_case` to False. We are setting `do_lower_case=False` for you but you may want to check this behavior.
| [en] dictionary: 40000 types
| [zh] dictionary: 40000 types
| loading model(s) from ../Paraphrase_Demo/models/enzh/checkpoint/checkpoint_2_152000.pt
Killed
```

Edit: the Flask app itself isn't actually starting, the server is killed during the imports at the top of api.py, before the app is ran. Also, the flask app runs fine in development mode.

Comment: Have you tried turning on more logging in the Flask app?

Comment: What’s the actual environment you’re running it in?  (You’ve tagged this with “docker” but don’t obviously mention Docker in the question.)  It “feels like” an out-of-memory error and you might see if `dmesg` reports the Linux OOM killer.

Comment: @kichik No I haven't

Comment: @DavidMaze I am running in a docker container from the "python:3" image.

Comment: What kind of Docker?  (Docker Toolbox, Docker for Mac/Windows, native Docker on a Linux host?)  Do you specify any kind of resource limits in _e.g._ a `docker run -m` option or a `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: I'm using Docker for Windows and I haven't specified any resource limits

Comment: @DavidMaze So how do I check for an out of memory error? I tried running `dmesg` but got `dmesg: read kernel buffer failed: Operation not permitted`, despite being root.